# set_error_handler, catch all function returning error

Tags: php

I have a custom exception class.

And I've set my error handler to call a custom catchall function, which would then throw an error.

```
class customError extends exception {}

function catchall($number, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new customError($number, $message, 0, $file, $line);
}
set_error_handler('catchall', -1 & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
```

I get the following error: `Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])`

Comment: As [the manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php), the constructor of the Exception class takes: `__construct ([ string $message = "" [, int $code = 0 [, Throwable $previous = NULL ]]] )`. Currently, you're not doing that. You're passing in `$number` where the `$message` should go, the `$message` where `$code` (int) should go etc. The error message does already tell you this.

Comment: Once you have the arguments in the right order, you can also delete `customError` and use [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/errorexception) instead

Comment: ^ This page of documentation also includes an example of `set_error_handler` that does *exactly* what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have switched the places...still get the same error.

Comment: The third argument should be an instance of Exception or null. What are you passing? You're currently passing `0`. Also, the forth and fifth argument won't do anything.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How would I pass an instance of Exception?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is what I have now `function catchall($message, $number,  $file, $line) {throw new customError($message, $number, null, $file, $line);}`

Comment: As @NiettheDarkAbsol already pointed out, you could just use `ErrorException` instead. And if you [check the manual about ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php), they have an example that does exactly what you're trying here. If you really want to throw your custom exception instead, just change `new ErrorException` to `new customError` in that code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't need to extend the Exception. The default one is enough for the use case. Everything seems to revolve around severity in the one you suggest. I don't need that!

Comment: Well, I don't think you can change how `set_error_handler()` and the `Exception`-class works because "you don't need that". Just copy/paste that code and you're set. _All_ exception classes (yours, the default `Exception` and `ErrorException`) takes the exact same arguments. All exceptions inherits the same `Exception`-class. You've been given the solution. It's up to you if you want to use it. I'm out...